# how to edit pom.xml and create a .jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, bluej

i have  a .jar file which has pom.xml .I want to add a dependency to it .I tried editing the pom.xml ,added the dependency ,zipped the file and renamed it to .jar .but when I include the .jar file it gives me the following error "error reading .jar,error in opening .zip file". I am using BlueJ.please help:(

my pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-pom</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</parent>

<name>GlassFish javaee.jar </name>
<artifactId>javaee</artifactId>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>../modules/javax.servlet-api.jar ../modules/endorsed/javax.annotation-api.jar ../modules/javax.ejb-api.jar ../modules/javax.transaction-api.jar ../modules/javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar ../modules/javax.management.j2ee-api.jar ../modules/javax.resource-api.jar ../modules/javax.security.auth.message-api.jar ../modules/javax.security.jacc-api.jar ../modules/webservices-osgi.jar ../modules/jaxb-osgi.jar ../modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar ../modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar ../modules/javax.xml.rpc-api.jar ../modules/javax.xml.registry-api.jar ../modules/javax.mail.jar ../modules/javax.faces.jar ../modules/javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar ../modules/javax.el.jar ../modules/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar ../modules/javax.persistence.jar ../modules/javax.jms-api.jar ../modules/bean-validator.jar ../modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar ../../mq/lib/jaxm-api.jar ../modules/javax.ws.rs-api.jar ../modules/javax.json.jar ../modules/javax.websocket-api.jar ../modules/javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar ../modules/javax.batch-api.jar</Class-Path>
                    <GlassFish-ServerExcluded>true</GlassFish-ServerExcluded>
                </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency></project>
```

i have already added the dependency i want.zipped the folder and renamed it to jar.but it gives me error as mentioned above.

Comment: Provide your pom.xml (or relevant parts if it is long), details on the dependency you are including and how you are building the project (if at all).

Comment: `pom.xml` is a project description file for if you build your project using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Use the [jar tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) for working with jar files.

Comment: Probably you zipped the directory one level to far up and your zip/jar file now contains a directory on its root level that then contains the jar-structure (META-INF, packages, etc.). Out of curiosity: What do you expect to happen after you successfully changed the POM file?

Comment: thanks Jesper,I used the jar tool and it worked fine:)